# error at using mysql in ubuntu access denied

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to use mysql but when I throw the command (sudo mysql) for use it . I get this error

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I already tried to reinstalling mysql with the commands:

apt-get remove -y mysql-*
apt-get purge -y mysql-*

sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

any help?

Comment: Did you check if MySQL auto-generated a default password for root? This is in the MySQL logs.

Comment: what i'ts exactly the ubication?

Comment: When MySQL gets installed it may randomize the password. This password is shown in the logs.